# Java FXScene Builder load into NetBeans throwing errors

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I'm trying to stumble through integrating fxml into java for a GUI for the final phase of a solution, and it's throwing errors on autogenerated code:

```
  <TableView layoutX="297.0" layoutY="156.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="523.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="64.0" text="Element" />
      <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="171.0" text="Weight Fraction" />
        <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="188.0" text="Atom Fraction" />
    </columns>
     <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" /> <-------
     </columnResizePolicy>
  </TableView>
```

is giving

```
Constant 'CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY' is not defined for 'TableView'
```

Given that I already am having trouble following the guide at https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm , specifically regarding the drag and drop functionality (dragging object into a make controller just gives xml instead of anything I can use), this is just further confusing.

Comment: Make sure you are using SceneBuilder 2.0 since there was a *lot* of changes in JavaFX's spec/API between the pre-release versions and JavaFX8 (supported by SceneBuilder 2.0)

Comment: Just checked and confirmed 2.0

Comment: Isn't this just a typo? `CONSTRANIED_RESIZE_POLICY` -> `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` ?

Comment: Indeed, code is copy paste, the error is hand typed, fixing.

Answer (score 1):

The application will still build and run correctly despite this error being shown in the IDE.  However, it is annoying to see false red explanation points all over the place.  So until a fix can be applied, a safe alternative is to set this property in the java code by using the TableView's columnResizePolicy method:

```
myTableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements) :

> The `<fx:constant>` element creates a reference to a class constant.

And this should just work fine with JavaFX 2.2 and later. There was a fix for this in :

[RT-19228 -  Defining TableView columnResizePolicy property with fxml](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19228)
.

If you are using an earlier version of JavaFX, you must upgrade it.

From the link that you have given, it seems you are using `SceneBuilder 1.0`, it might be a reason for the issue. Try upgrading it.

Comment: It's being generated as per JavaFX Scene Builder producing an .fxml when saved, that's all I know.

Comment: The fxml is just fine, which JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: Then you must upgrade it, the fix was made for JavaFX 2.2. If you use an earlier version, the fxml doesn't identify it. Please check the issue linked in the answer.

Comment: Where does one get 2.2?  I had to hunt through Oracle to even find this download, and there were no other download options.

Comment: Install [JDK 8.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). It comes with JavaFX 8, which is the latest and the recommended version to use.

Comment: My mistake, I was speaking for the scene builder, which is 2.0

Properties indicates my JavaFX is 8.0.45

Comment: I just tried your code and it works just perfectly on Java 1.8.0_45.

Comment: You can get SceneBuilder v 8 from [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/), though it likely will not integrate directly with an IDE (yet).

Comment: JavaFX8 and SceneBuilder 2.0 is what you want. JavaFX8 comes with JDK 8. JavaFX2, 2.1, and 2.2 were Pre-Spec releases of JavaFX (do not use them). I think the confusion is coming from people referring to SceneBuilder as JavaFX, it's not... it's just a tool.

Comment: Then how do I move forward on this?

Also, itachi, that link is behind a login wall

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working FXML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Element" />
          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Weight Fraction" />
            <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Atom Fraction" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

This is approximately what you had above, except it has the rest of the structure for the file. You must make sure your `TableView` control is nested in a `Container`, but I assume you have that already.

Then in your startup code, you must create an `FXMLLoader` and load this FXML document, which will auto-gen all the UI view code. You must have a Controller and can either specify the Controller via the `FXMLLoader` at runtime, or specify it in the FXML document (look in the bottom-left side of SceneBuilder for the place to paste the package.subpackage.ClassName of your controller.

Here is an example from a project which loads FXML from disk:

https://github.com/MoneyBeets/Narvaro/blob/master/src/java/edu/csus/ecs/moneybeets/narvaro/Narvaro.java#L137

Here's an example from a little more simple of a project:

https://github.com/SnakeDoc/superD/blob/master/src/com/vanomaly/superd/Main.java#L37